# Create a pull down menu / div in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I would like to achieve something similar like the pull down menu from android in a webapp:
http://cdn4.droidmatters.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/android-notifications.jpg

Basically I want to pull in a menu, toolbar, components etc. into the screen from the top, left, right, bottom. Now I already found something basic using jquery-ui resizable function

```
$("#menuContainer").resizable();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JXeWA/46/

The difference being, that the revealed div is quite static. So i doesn't move down with the element, it is already fully there and therefore "only" exposed. If you compare that to something like the android pull-down status bar: here you get the impression that the element is really pulled down with the finger. It is successive revealed while you pull the element into the display - hope that makes sence, it's hard to explain.

Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: Well you have animate property then start,stop, resize events http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/ .
I don't see a problem to achieve more complex UI behavior.
Try, then try again and post whatever particular issue you have If not succeed.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would go about it...

CSS:

```
#menuContainer{
     position:relative;
     background-color:#A3155C;
     overflow:hidden;
     height:10px;
     padding:5px 5px 12px 5px;
}
#ddMenu{
    position:absolute;
    top:25%;
    width:100%;
    display:none;
}
#grippie{
     height:16px;
     display:inline-block;
     position:absolute;
     left:50%;
     bottom:0px;
     color:#FFF;
     -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    width:40px;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var h = parseInt($("#menuContainer").css('height')); //height mentioned in css - feel free to change

$("#menuContainer").resizable({ 
        handles: {
            "s":"#grippie"   
        },
        maxHeight:50, 
        minHeight:0,
        resize: function(){
            if($(this).height()<=h){
                 $("#ddMenu").hide();
            }else{
                $("#ddMenu").show();
            }

        }
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/JXeWA/112/

Hope this is what you are looking for. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Thanks. Thats already looking a lot more than what I meant. After playing around with it, I figured that the resizable function does already what I want to do, just the other way around. Hence I created a fiddle, where I increased the size of the resizable div.

Comment: I can still only add one direction (pull down.. well which now translated to up) but that can probably be solved in a clean way with more than on resizable element.
http://jsfiddle.net/versus_django/JXeWA/180/

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is a sort of pull followed by animation it would be a little bit hard with jQuery UI. The tip I come up within my mind is you pull the menu then trigger 'mouseup' or whatever event to release the menu and then continue with animation. It might be buggy, though.